# Как защитить сайт от посторонних ссылок?

Tags: python-3.x, http, безопасность, flask

Сайт написан на Flask. На него часто приходят запросы типа `GET *левый сайт* HTTP/1.1`. На некоторые flask кидает 404, а на некоторые 200. Меня пугает, что на такие странные запросы он кидает 200 ответ. Еще такие запросы приходят: `178.149.185.231 - - [06/Sep/2017 22:19:37] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type("îV\x9dÿÐG\x0fÔc\x0fXØ$\x1aõ\x02Áju\x9eÖR']\x1bõ")Èzæ»" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Стоит ли опасаться таких запросов и как от них избавиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Записи в логе выглядят как будто вашим сервером как прокси пытаются воспользоваться.

Запросы со ссылкой (absolute-URI) вместо просто пути, http-клиенты должны только прокси-серверам отправлять, хотя rfc для HTTP/1.1 не запрещает явно запросы со ссылками ([rfc 7230 absolute-form](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.2)):

> To allow for transition to the absolute-form for all requests in some
> future version of HTTP, a server MUST accept the absolute-form in
> requests, even though HTTP/1.1 clients will only send them in
> requests to proxies.

Учитывая, что у нас уже есть следующая версия [HTTP/2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540), которая по другому работает, то поддерживать ссылки вместо пути из-за совместимости с воображаемой будущей версией не стоит.

Вернуть ли 200 ответ, если домен в ссылке совпадает с ожидаемым `Host` заголовком (dns запрос не следует делать), вернуть ли 400 ответ для "левых доменов" или просто соединение разорвать — от вас зависит (rfc 7230):

> Once the effective request URI has been constructed, an origin server
> needs to decide whether or not to provide service for that URI via
> the connection in which the request was received.

Разные сервера по разному себя ведут. К примеру, nginx можно настроить отбрасывать подобные запросы: [`if ($request ~* ^https?://) { return 444; }`](https://serverfault.com/a/413781/3933).

flask встроенный сервер не рассчитан, чтобы его напрямую в интернет выставлять: *"Flask’s built-in server is not suitable for production."* Посмотрите, какие [другие опции доступны для развертывания web-приложения, написанного с помощью flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/deploying/).

Comment: А в каком смысле не предназначен напрямую? Т.е. им стоит пользоваться только локально?

Comment: @kot_mapku3: встроенный сервер называется "development server" — он предназначен для разработки и тестирования. [Is the server bundled with Flask safe to use in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12269537/4279)